# How do I escape "@g" in sed (with the -global setting)?

Tags: shell, sed

I have many repositories with the remote origin set to HTTPS. Now I want to change all origin remotes to SSH.

I am using a command for this in which I want to replace all preceeding url = `https://gitlab.mypath/` with `git@gitlab.maypath:`.

Is there a way to express this with one sed call. Something like:

```
's@https://gitlab.mypath/@git@gitlab.mypath:@g'
```

I have to be able to escape the first "@g"

Comment: Switch from `s@@@` to `s|||`?

Comment: @Cyrus Do you mean s| h t t p s ://gitlab.bla/|@git@gitlab.bla:|g

Comment: @Cyrus This was the solution. I am very excited and thank you a lot. This saves me so much time and I also learned something. Woaw.

Comment: sunshine, you can post an answer and [self-accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) it after 48 hours. That's the preferred way to mark a question as solved when nobody else has posted an answer.

Comment: @sunshine: The character after the `s` specifies the separator, which must occur three times in your `s` command.

Comment: Apart from choosing any character for the delimiter, you can also escape that character: `\@`.

Comment: @bad_coder Now that I know that, what follows s is a delimiter, yes. But back than I didnot know even that it is a delimiter. This question is answered already and can be closed

Answer (score 0):

**The correct anwers**

1. Switch from `s@@@` to `s|||`
2. Apart from choosing any character for the delimiter, you can also escape that character: @

**The explanation**

The character after the s specifies the separator, which must occur three times in your s command.

**Thanks**

@Cyrus @dan

Comment: Please refrain from answering common duplicates. Once you earn enough reputation, you will be able to vote to close; until then, probably concentrate on answering questions which are not obvious FAQs.